# How to assign different years corresponding to Year column in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
  Year   NFF
1 500 0.026290755
2 501 0.013948372
3 502 -0.00848134
4 503 -0.02411562
5 504 -0.01762948
6 505 -0.0190660
```

I want to have different years to `Year` column. Like year 500 should be 1850, year 501 should be 1851, 502 should be 1852 and so on. How can I do this in R?

Comment: `df$Year <- df$Year + 1350`.

Comment: Why don't you just add 1350 to your year column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic first posted by Rui Barradas and deschen.
Here a `dplyr` implementation.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Year = Year + 1350)
```

Output:

```
   Year      NFF
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1  1850  0.0263 
2  1851  0.0139 
3  1852 -0.00848
4  1853 -0.0241 
5  1854 -0.0176 
6  1855 -0.0191
```

Data:

```
df <- tribble(
~Year,   ~NFF,
500, 0.026290755, 
501, 0.013948372, 
502, -0.00848134, 
503, -0.02411562, 
504, -0.01762948, 
505, -0.0190660)
```